# How do I upload an unpublished app from my developer console to my device?

Tags: android

I uploaded a new version of my app to my Android developer console.  But how do I actually get that app from the console to my phone?

The app is published.  But the current version that I need to test is un-published. So how do I get the unpublished version to my phone?

Thanks!

Comment: How did you make the app?

Comment: @AaronMcIver I usually test on my own device using the adb tool. This time I need to test billing so I as I understand it, I need to have the app in the console. I made the app in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply reinstall your application

1. Uninstall application

   adb uninstall package_name
2. Install your dev version

   adb install app.apk

Comment: I have been doing adb installs, but this time I need to get the app from the developer console

Comment: I see 2 options: first - to build older version of application from source (if you use version control) and second to install this application from Play market as normal application (you need to remove all versions from phone and wait some time while Play will catch your changes)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to export the .apk file and copy in to your phone. Then you can install it.
If you are using Eclipse (with Emulator), the file is in the bin directory after you run the app in Emulator.

Comment: I have been doing adb installs, but this time I need to get the app from the developer console